# Dask compute (to catch errors), but keep results on workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'd like to define a set of actions and run them on the dask workers, and catch any errors that may arise without having to call compute and bring the results to the client.

For instance, if I do astype(int) on an object column, this should give me an error. When I use client.persist, this doesn't give me an error back.

```
column = df['string column'].astype(int)
client.persist(column)
```

However, client.compute does throw this error:

```
column = df['string column'].astype(int)
client.compute(column)
# ValueError ... Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Is there a way to get errors immediately as in compute, but not force Dask to return a result to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
column = column.persist()
dask.distributd.wait(column)
```